# Oven element wire lead melted to back panel, not heating

Tags: electrical, appliances

I have a Frigidaire oven, about 1 year old. Several days ago when turning the oven on there was a spark, 'pop' noise, and then the oven shut off. Flipping the break returned power, but now the oven won't heat.
The heating coil has continuity so I pulled the back panel off, and the orange wire lead to one side of the heating element appears to have melted into the back panel of the oven. I'm guessing the contact caused some type of short.
Can I simply replace the melted lead or is the unit otherwise damaged?

Comment: I'd be looking for a warranty repair. Surely it's still under warranty. Start messing with it yourself and you could void the warranty.

Comment: Agree with @GeorgeAnderson While the warranty is likely "1 year", big companies are often interested in avoiding (a) upset customers and (b) recalls. So it is worth contacting the manufacturer, even if it is a little after the warranty period.

Comment: You said the element had continuity, did you check the element to ground? Cal rods many times short to ground and there is usually a hole in the element , this could have been the root cause that fried the wire I would look on the 1/2 element side that the wire fried for the damage to the element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @EdBeal, I'll give that a go while waiting for Frigidaire to respond. Not ideal to have a non-working oven this time of year!